# VoIP and Callkit framework audio issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, voip

I am using VoIP Push and Callkit Framework for audio and video call feature in my app. I am able to display incoming call screen when app is in background mode.

I am facing one issue, that is when I answer the call, I am hearing my own voice again from device speaker.So please help me to resolve this issue.

I checked with the Speakerbox sample app given by apple developer, It that also same thing happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be the setup of the IOUnit in AudioController.mm.

Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034409/3990192